# Migrate a Question - Best Practice

Tags: discussion, migration

I've been advised from others that a question that doesn't have any comments or answers shouldn't be migrated, even if it is clearly more appropriate for another site.  I don't fully understand the reasoning behind this other than for the purpose of just requiring the original poster to delete and repost the question on the proper site.  Is this the practice that should be followed then when coming across a question that is better suited for another site?  Do we recommend to the poster to repost or...?

Comment: To be more clear, I commented on a post from another user that was better suited for another site.  Stating that it was and also that it was subjective and showed no research attempt made by the asking user.  I also flagged it to be migrated.  What part of this process should I have done differently?

Comment: Okay, I understand.  Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/160917, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273585/160917

Comment: @D.W. Thank you. These posts are much clearer. This is very helpful.